# Invoking command stored in a variable in zsh

Tags: command-line, zsh

This works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cmd="ls -l"
${cmd}
```

But change it to run under Z shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
cmd="ls -l"
${cmd}
```

And I get:

```
./testing.sh:3: command not found: ls -l
```

Why, and how do I make it work under zsh?  The full script I am working on requires zsh.

Same problem is present for both builtins and external commands; e.g., replacing `ls -l` with `touch something` exhibits same difference?  What's up with this?  Thx!

Comment: Beside the point, but `ls` and `touch` are both external commands.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Use an array instead of a string (recommended)

   ```
   cmd=(ls -l)
   $cmd
   ```
2. Split the string into words

   ```
   cmd='ls -l'
   $=cmd
   ```

Source: [What is word splitting? Why is it important in shell programming?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26661/117037)